# Android emulator flickering after upgrading to Hedgehog

Tags: android, macos-sonoma

I upgraded to android hedgehog on Mac os Sonoma and figured that the emulator keeps on flickering. Initially, I thought it could be an issue with my project and to rule that possibility out I created a new project and figured that the same issue was duplicable. Is this a hedgehog issue?

Any workaround to fix the flickering issue?

Note: I have sufficient memory on my device.